# worldpay payment gateway api showing method not allowed error

Tags: php, worldpay

I tried this api format for tokenization in worldpay payment gateway. i got method not allowed response. what is error in this method.

https://api.worldpay.com/v1/tokens?clientkey=mykey&name=namee&expiryMonth=2&expiryyear=2025&issuenumber=1&startmonth=2&startyear=2018&cardnumber=4444333322221111&type=Card&cvc=123

I got this error while trying.

```
{"httpStatusCode":405,
"customCode":"HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
"message":"Request method 'GET' not supported",
"description":"Requested HTTP method is not supported",
"errorHelpUrl":null,
"originalRequest":"api.worldpay.com/v1/…"}
```

Comment: Show us some code and error that occur while trying to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: i got error like this " 
 {"httpStatusCode":405,"customCode":"HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"Request method 'GET' not supported","description":"Requested HTTP method is not supported","errorHelpUrl":null,"originalRequest":"http://api.worldpay.com/v1/tokens?clientkey=mykey&name=namee&expiryMonth=2&expiryyear=2025&issuenumber=1&startmonth=2&startyear=2018&cardnumber=4444333322221111&type=Card&cvc=123"}

Comment: It's exactly what it says. You are not supposed to use `GET` method on the api. Please read it's documentation and use `POST` or whatever is mentioned on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send `POST` request instead of `GET` request. Use `cURL`

Example:

```
// set post fields values
$post = [
    'clientkey' => 'your_key',
    'name' => 'Some Name', // etc.
];

$ch = curl_init('https://api.worldpay.com/v1/tokens');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);

//do something with $response
```